# How to create a dummy value column in MySQL depending on the Table specific information was selected from?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables that contain information about users. One table, `current_users` keeps track of current users and the other table, `new_users`, contains data of users who have recently submitted their information. The information in both tables are identical in terms of attributes but the information is kept in separate for reasons.

As of right now I am selecting the information and LEFT JOIN-ing both `new_users` and `current_users` onto a table that has information of where these users have attended an event. Because other people work with these tables, I can't change the table by adding a column so I need a way to differentiate what information comes from what table in a SQL statement.

The SELECT statement as of right now selects from both tables simultaneously:

`SELECT current_users.lastname, current_users.firstname, current_users.id, new_users,lastname, new_users.firstname, new_users.id`

But I would like a way to create a dummy column that stores 1 whether current_users columns are NULL or stores 0 when new_users is NULL. Any advice?

Comment: If you are doing a LEFT JOIN, how can `current_users` (the left-hand table) ever be NULL?  And what column(s) are you joining on, `id`?

Comment: @PinnyM I simplified my problem a little too much... I apologize. There is a third table that both tables are left-joining on based on an event number. So they can have null values. I didn't want to disclose any information that may be irrelevant haha... ><

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT current_users.lastname, 
       current_users.firstname, 
       current_users.id, 
       new_users,lastname, 
       new_users.firstname, 
       new_users.id,
       CASE WHEN new_users.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as dummy_column
```

Comment: This helped me with my problem. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

create a view, maybe ?

```
create or replace view all_users
as 
 (select 0 as user_type, lastname, firstname, id from current_users
 UNION
 select 1 as user_type, lastname, firstname, id from new_users)
```

Comment: This is a great answer but my friend told me it doesn't specifically help our situation. `new_users` is constantly changing (I believe every month or so we dump the `news_users` into the `current_users` and my friend said it might screw up with the View.) I apologize for not mentioning that in my question. This definitely would be the answer I would accept if not for that reason.